# iText 7 pdhHtml keep table rows together

Tags: itext7

I am new in iText 7, i am developing a spa project (asp.net, c#, and angularjs), where i need to implement a report for existing html page.I found iText 7 (.Net) has a easy way to implement it. Using below code of line, that's return me a byte array and i can easily show in browser as pdf also can download.

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);              converterProperties.SetBaseUri(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlText, memStream, converterProperties);
```

In my raw html there has some html tables (every table has some particular rows) and i want to keep them in a page (i mean if table rows not fit in a single page then start from next page). I got a solution like below

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Test");
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    table.addCell("key " + i);
    table.addCell("value " + i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    document.add(p);
}
// Try to keep the table on 1 page
table.setKeepTogether(true);
document.add(table);
```

But in my case i cannot implement like that way because content already exist in html tables (in my existing html page).

Advance thanks, if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done using a custom *TagWorkerFactory* and *TableTagWorker* class.
Take a look at the code samples below.

The first thing we should do is create a custom TableTagWorker that tells iText to keep the table together. We do this using the code you've mentioned: *table.setKeepTogether(true)*.

```
class CustomTableTagWorker extends TableTagWorker{

    public CustomTableTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void processEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super.processEnd(element, context);
        ((com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table) getElementResult()).setKeepTogether(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see the only thing we changed on our custom TableTagWorker is the fact that it has to keep the table together.

The next step would be to create a custom *TagWorkerFactory* that maps our *CustomTableTagWorker* to the *table* tag in HTML. We do this like so:

```
class CustomTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory{
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (tag.name().equalsIgnoreCase("table")) {
            return new CustomTableTagWorker(tag, context); // implements ITagWorker
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}
```

All we do here is tell iText that if it finds a *table* tag it should pass the element to the *CustomTableTagWorker*, in order to be converted to a PDF object (where setKeepTogether == true).

The last step is registering this *CustomTagWorkerFactory* on our *ConverterProperties*.

```
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HTML, new FileOutputStream(DEST), converterProperties);
```

Using these code samples I was able to generate an output PDF where tables, if small enough to render on an entire page, will never be split across multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue of trying to keep together content within a div. I applied the following css property and this kept everything together. This worked with itext7 pdfhtml.

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```